# Format IEEE Tran Itemizethanks

Tags: itemize, ieeetran, author-number, journal

I am writing a paper using IEEE Tran (bare_jrnl_compsoc). When I added the following code I have a blank page in the beginning.

```
\author{Md~Osman~Gani, Taskina~Fayezeen, Sheikh~Iqbal~Ahamed,
    Richard~J.~Povinelli, Roger~O.~Smith, Muhammad~Arif, and~Ahmed~J.~Kattan}
    % <-this % stops a space
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem M. O. Gani, T. Fayezeen,and S. I. Ahamed are with the Department of Mathematics, Statistics, and Computer Science, Marquette University, Milwaukee, WI, USA 53233.\protect\\
E-mail: md.gani@mu.edu, taskina.fayezeen@mu.edu, sheikh.ahamed@mu.edu}
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem R. J. Povinelli is with the Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Marquette University, Milwaukee, WI, USA 53233.\protect\\
E-mail: richard.povinelli@mu.edu}

\thanks {Manuscript received April 25, 2016; revised August 26, 2016.}
% The paper headers
\markboth{IEEE Transaction on Mobile Computing, ~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2016}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals}
```

I have the following output and the article starts from the 2nd page.

```
First Page:
```

[image: The first page has nothing but the footnote numbers]

```
Second Page:
```

[image: The article starts from the second page]

Would you please let me know what am I doing wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: Please post code that's compilable, rather than a few code snippets.

Comment: Is there any news here? With the information given, nobody can answer your question. It is unclear.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was due to misplacing of the end curly brace of the "\author" item.

Initially, I placed the end curly brace of the "\author" item right after the authors names, like this:

```
\author{ <Author 1>, <Author2>}
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{
     \IEEEcompsocthanksitem <Author 1> 
     \IEEEcompsocthanksitem <Author2>}
\thanks{ Manuscript received ... }
```

But it needs to be placed after all the thanks item. Here is the correct code:

```
\author{ <Author 1>, <Author2>
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{
     \IEEEcompsocthanksitem <Author 1> 
     \IEEEcompsocthanksitem <Author2>}
\thanks{ Manuscript received ... }}
```

Now it produces the desired output and article starts from the very first page.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to using `\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks` twice.

Try the following -

```
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem <Author 1> 
                      \IEEEcompsocthanksitem <Author2>}
```

Comment: Thanks! It did reduce the footnote number from 5 to 2 but the article still starts from the 2nd page. I have "\thanks" item right after the "\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks" item. I think the "\thanks" item giving number 2 footnote.